# QT open not existing database

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt

I've created simple function for connecting with sqlite3 database. But I've recognized that it makes connection , even if database file not exist

As you can see below : I've tried to check if file really exist and if it's really connected .

```
bool DatabaseConnection::make_connection(const QString &path)
{

    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setDatabaseName(path);

    #ifdef QT_DEBUG
        qDebug() << "File: '" + db.databaseName() + "' exist = " << QFileInfo::exists(db.databaseName());
        qDebug() << db.isValid();
    #endif

    if (!db.open())
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(nullptr,
            QObject::tr("Error - Cannot open database"),
            QObject::tr("Failed attempt to establish connection \n"),
            QMessageBox::Close);
        return false;
    }
    qDebug() <<"Open:" <<db.isOpen();
    qDebug() << "errors:" << db.isOpenError();
    return true;
}
```

after changing path name on first compilation - file not exist , but connection seems to be established (True).

In next compilation tells that file exist ( I've couldn't find it anywhere) , and again connection is 'established'

Comment: The explanation is that `QSqlDatabase` creates a database file (on close) even if it wasn't initially exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar problem, db.open() creates new file if it doesn't exist.
Just wrap db.open() arround QFileInfo::exists(path).

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you attempt to access an SQLite3 database that does not exist, it will create one. So db.open() will attempt to create a database file if one is not found. You would be best served checking if the DB file exists first using some other method before calling db.open().